# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter - How to grab the last item?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I need to grab the **last List Item** (CardView) coming from a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter in order do add extra bottom padding to it.

The problem is that the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter works a bit differently than a RecyclerView and doesn't have an Array or List of items passed to it, but a Firebase Database Reference.

So I can't do this. For example:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHolder userViewHolder, int position) {

   if( position == getItemCount() - 1 ){
      // Your last item
   }
```

}

Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my try that might help you:

`FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount()` as its docementation is copied from `RecyclerView.Adapter` (still no big difference):

> Returns the total number of items in the data set held by the adapter.

Instead of `onBindViewHolder()` you can do that in `populateViewHolder()`:

```
@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(VH viewHolder, T model, int position)
{
    if (position == getItemCount() - 1)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this if you want to use onBindViewHolder

```
LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mLinearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    mLinearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

and override onBindViewHolder

```
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(mViewHelper viewHolder, int position) {
            if(position ==  0){
                viewHolder.button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            }
            super.onBindViewHolder(viewHolder, position);
        }
```

and

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
```